# avoiding ScriptRegistrar with Telerik components

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have an MVC site which uses the Telerik Grid control.

When I use their ScriptRegistrar to include the desired .js files, everything works fine and the files it includes are:

```
telerik.common.min.js
telerik.textbox.min.js
telerik.calendar.min.js
telerik.datepicker.min.js
telerik.grid.min.js
telerik.grid.filtering.min.js
```

However, if I include these same files using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/telerik.common.min.js"></script>
....*all the others*....
```

and totally take out the ScriptRegistrar (I want to do this because I want to use the MVC4 bundling support instead) the grid does not load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of problem is ScriptRegisterar add some JQuery scripts into your page for startup action. I think I have two work-arounds :

**1st:**

You can just add "telerik.common.min.js" file through ScriptRegisterar and add other telerik script files through MVC 4 bundling component. If you do so, Telerik tries to load related script files at run time. For example If you have a ComboBox in your page, Telerik add some scripts to load the script after page load. It ignores loading if it was loaded previously.

OR

**2nd:**

You can find and analyze the injected startup script file. As I checked , It can be something like this (but further investemnt is needed)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if(!jQuery.telerik) jQuery.telerik = {};
jQuery.telerik.cultureInfo={"shortDate":"yyyy/MM/dd","longDate":"yyyy/MM/dd","longTime":"hh:mm:ss tt","shortTime":"hh:mm tt","fullDateTime":"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt","sortableDateTime":"yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd\u0027T\u0027HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss","universalSortableDateTime":"yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss\u0027Z\u0027","generalDateShortTime":"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt","generalDateTime":"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt","monthDay":"MMMM dd","monthYear":"MMMM, yyyy","days":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],"abbrDays":["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],"shortestDays":["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],"abbrMonths":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"months":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""],"am":"ق.ظ","pm":"ب.ظ","dateSeparator":"/","timeSeparator":":","firstDayOfWeek":0,"currencydecimaldigits":2,"currencydecimalseparator":"/","currencygroupseparator":",","currencygroupsize":3,"currencynegative":3,"currencypositive":2,"currencysymbol":"ريال","numericdecimaldigits":2,"numericdecimalseparator":".","numericgroupseparator":",","numericgroupsize":3,"numericnegative":3,"percentdecimaldigits":2,"percentdecimalseparator":".","percentgroupseparator":",","percentgroupsize":3,"percentnegative":0,"percentpositive":0,"percentsymbol":"%"};
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible (or rather, feasible) to avoid using the script registrar. If you want to load the resource files (.css/.js) seperately, you can do that.

You will still need a script registrar on the page because it 'injects' custom javascript according to customizations you have made on the telerik controls (ex. Grid).